# Error in Node: GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, backend, node-modules

We're following a microservice architecture and we have internal API calls to get responses from other microservices.
We have noticed that one out of five times API is failing with the below error:

> error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN - Error:
> getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN at
> GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)

Can anybody guide us for the same?

Comment: I have similar problem with postgres.js library. Mine doesn't work even on first connection. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, not yet. But will post an answer as soon as I get any solution.

Comment: I use docker. And I was trying to connect postgres.js to PG database. I was using my container name as host, but changing it to host.docker.internal solved the issue. It was related to proxy. Maybe, it can help you.